# What if Kloc stops offering help in Reigns?

Tags: reigns

The year is 2036, I

> have got the help of Kloc because I gave him a strawberry a long time ago. And I never asked him to actually help because I wanted to save him for later. In the life I gave the strawberry to him, I eventually died and since then Kloc never showed up again.
>  Before the devil came for the last time, I was invited to Lamaskus and accepted, so I got another strawberry (Because why not).
>  Now I have had the devil's death wish curse for the past few lives but Kloc never shows up.

Is this a bug? What did I do wrong or what can I still do to succeed tricking the devil?

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReignsGame/comments/6xq5qp/i_already_gave_kloc_the_strawberry_and_he/) sounds like I should not have

> said "no" to kloc when he asked to help me before the devil came.

Is this actually a problem?

And [this steamcommunity thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/474750/discussions/0/3288067088115681812/) says to just keep

> saying "No" to everyone until Kloc appears.

Answer (score 1):

Since there were no answers here, I've decided to continue playing and saying No to everybody. Finally at some point, Kloc appeared. However, not, as others in the internet claimed, when a resource was low, but seemingly at random.

So it is annoying to live many lifes without any real choice but at least it was still doable in my case, despite having another strawberry. (I find it weird that I was offered to go to Lamaskus when I already had solved that.)